# Python Read From File

Tags: python, file, function

So I have this Python code I'm working on where I open up a file and read the maximum and minimum score percentage from it and then display the teams with the max score as well as the teams with the min score that being 0.75 and 0.125
I keep getting this error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.75'
```

I'd appreciate any help please and thank you.

This is the file I'm working with http://www.filedropper.com/nfldata

Here is my code:

```
def create_score_list(nfl_file):
    """Create a list of teams and scores from nfl_file."""
    # 2a create a score list and initialize it to empty
    score_list = []

for line in nfl_file:              # 2b. get each line from the file
    if line[0:28] == 'National Football Conference' or\
             'NFC EAST' in line or\
             'NFC NORTH' in line or\
             'NFC SOUTH' in line or\
             'NFC WEST' in line or\
             'AFC EAST' in line or\
             'AFC NORTH' in line or\
             'AFC SOUTH' in line or\
             'AFC WEST' in line:   
        continue                 # skip header line
    line_list = line.split(',')           # 2bI. csv => split on comma
    # create tuple:
    team_tuple = (int(line_list[4]), line_list[0])
    score_list.append(team_tuple)        # 2bII. append tuple
return score_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because sometimes `line_list[4]` is a `float` and sometimes is a `string`. But you are parsing it always as an `int`. Also, You need to filter first your CSV values to skip the headers, you are doing it now like this:

```
if line[0:28] == 'National Football Conference' or\
        'American Football Conference' in line or\
        'NFC EAST' in line or\
        'NFC NORTH' in line or\
        'NFC SOUTH' in line or\
        'NFC WEST' in line or\
        'AFC EAST' in line or\
        'AFC NORTH' in line or\
        'AFC SOUTH' in line or\
        'AFC WEST' in line:
```

But you are missing some cases. You can simplify it by just checking if the value in `line_list[4]` is a `float`.

```
try:
    score = float(line_list[4])
except ValueError:
    continue # The value isn't a float
```

So `create_score_list(nfl_file)` would be:

```
def create_score_list(nfl_file):
    """Create a list of teams and scores from nfl_file."""
    # 2a create a score list and initialize it to empty
    score_list = []

    for line in nfl_file:              # 2b. get each line from the file
        line_list = line.split(',')           # 2bI. csv => split on comma
        score = None
        try:
            score = float(line_list[4])
        except ValueError:
            continue # The value isn't a float

        # create tuple:
        team_tuple = (score, line_list[0])
        score_list.append(team_tuple)        # 2bII. append tuple
    return score_list
```

Comment: yeah the string problem is what I was facing but I get what you did thanks for your help really appreciate it !

Comment: I'm glad that this worked for you. If this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. :)